# Automatic testing of examples in documentation

Tags: python, testing, sage

In the end of the [SageMath manual](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/afterword.html) they explain why they chose to implement SageMath in Python. One of the items says: "Excellent support for documentation of functions and packages in the source code, including automatic extraction of documentation and **automatic testing of all examples. The examples are automatically tested regularly and guaranteed to work as indicated.**"

This sounds neat, but I haven't found the way to do it. How can I automatically test all the examples that appear in the documentation to my functions?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?  In principle, you should be able to just do `sage -t path/to/myfile.sage`, though there are sometimes complications like https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-devel/HL8FWsId11M

Comment: Or if you mean Sage's examples, just do `make test` or `sage -ptestall` or something like that, see http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/developer/doctesting.html

Comment: I meant to test my own files (like in your first comment). I also found here: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/developer/doctesting.html#beyond-the-sage-library  an explanation of how to write tests inside examples.

Comment: So you are saying that `sage -t path/to/myfile.sage` doesn't work for you when you write the tests as in the documentation, with exactly that syntax?

Comment: It works. I am saying that your comment solved my question.  I looked for a solution in Python, but in fact the solution was in Sage. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I've made that an answer so that others searching for this know it's got an answer - accept if it is indeed solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you can write your examples using [this syntax](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/developer/doctesting.html#beyond-the-sage-library). Then, you should be able to just do

```
sage -t path/to/myfile.sage
```

and apparently that works, given the comment thread!